# C++ - How to find a (variable) character in a string?

Tags: c++, string, character

I'm required to find a character **entered by the user** in a for loop. I'd usually do

- if (sentence[i] == 'e')

but since here, 'e' will be a one letter char variable, I don't know how to get that value to be compared. I can't just enter

- if (sentence[i] == thechar)

but I also can't create a variable to contain the character in between quotation marks like

- char2 = "\'" + thechar + "\'";

So how do I do it in this context? I'm not allowed to use other, more effective, more advanced methods. This is a basics course. Please help!

Comment: *I'm required to find a character* - Something in quotation marks is not a character.

Comment: What's wrong with `char c = 'e'; if (c == sentence[i]) { /*...*/}`?

Comment: It might not be 'e'. I have to cin >> thechar. So if user enters u, my condition will have to check for 'u' but I don't know how to create a variable that converts string u to string 'u'. I do not get the { /*...*/} part.

Comment: @blue0, `''` is for character literals. Once you have a `char`, you don't need to add the single quotation marks or anything special.

Answer (score 3):

```
string word;
char letter;
cout << "Enter a word\n";
cin >> word;
cout << "What letter would you like to search for?\n";
cin >> letter;
for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
{
    if (word[i] == letter)
    {
        cout << letter << " is the " << i + 1 << "character of " << word << endl;
    }
}
```

You can create a variable where you ask for the letter the user wants, and use that variable to compare.

Comment: Thank you very much. All I was taught is to declare strings as char word[maxwordlength]; so I tried to work that way. In the end this is better done the same way as pretty much all other languages.

Answer (score 1):

To find position of chosen letter you can use `std::string.find(...)`

```
std::string str = "My house is white.";
std::size_t pos = str.find('s');
std::cout << "Position: " << pos << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
Position: 6
```

For more informations go to http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/ page.